# Render a template inside wysiwyg text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, wysiwyg

I have a *@page.content* that is stored in database as a *text* column. Is there an easy way to embed a render tag inside that html content?

```
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
<%= render 'image_slider' %>
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: are you looking for `eval`

Comment: `@page.content` is a string and you can `render_to_string 'image_slider'` and then do the insert or sub to `@page.content`. If this seems crude, use nokogiri. Also, you could insert needed tags with javascript on client side, pretty easy with jquery.

Comment: 2nithing thanks for your answer. I don't understand how to use eval to solve this. Can u provide some code to explain?

Comment: 2 Ivan Misic thanks 4 sharing your ideas. I'm going to give a try to the nokogiri-way and if it will not work will go with js

Answer (score 0):

I choose the nokogiri way and finished with two urly helpers

```
  def print_content_start( page, shift=4 )
    result = ''
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML( page.content )
    doc.css('div,p').each_with_index do |node, i|
      break if i == shift
      result += node.to_s
    end
    result
  end

  def print_content_end( page, shift=4 )
    result = ''
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML( page.content )
    doc.css('div,p').drop( shift ).each do |node|
      result += node.to_s
    end
    result
  end
```

If anyone knows a better way, please let me know!